# base64_encode() with chinese characters

Tags: php, base64, character

I'm currently finishing of an ecard system that allows users to send cards to other people by mail.

The mail also contains a link to view the same card in the browser, this link is basically generated by encoding the text with `base64_encode()`

```
'http://www.test.com/ecards?card=' . base64_encode('your text'); // like this
```

This works fine for english text, but once I enter some Chinese and visit the link, the characters are all messed up

```
汉��N�B��Y][ۘ[�[�\�N�9�(�*���B�[�Z[��0��q��B��[\Y�YY�[�\�N�9cc�+�N�B��Y][ۘ[�[�\�N�:#��*���B��[�\�N�9.+y���
```

I has nothing to do with my charset, it's set to UTF-8, I even printed the same Chinese text and it's showing up perfectly.

So I'm wondering if `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` might have something to do with this.

```
// Doesn't work
echo base64_decode($body);

// Chinese characters show up fine!!!!
echo 'simplified Chinese: 汉语; <br />';
echo 'traditional Chinese: 漢語; <br />';
echo 'Pinyin: Hànyǔ; <br />';
echo 'simplified Chinese: 华语; <br />';
echo 'traditional Chinese: 華語; <br />';
echo 'Chinese: 中文; <br />';
```

EDIT: When I try outputting $_GET[] when using an url like http://www.test.com/ecards?card=中文, it works fine.
So it's clearly the `base64_encode` or `base64_decode` that can't handle Chinese characters.

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking a PHP question. Otherwise, edit your question to change the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `base64_` functions do not operate on characters, they operate on bytes. They will happily convert anything you pass in without error.

Your problem here is that the encoding of the characters you are using as input does not match the encoding of the page where they are displayed after decoding. Where does "your text" come from? If it's from a form submission, you need to make sure that the page where the form appears is displayed using the same encoding as the "view card" page, *or* that the form has an `accept-charset` attribute matching the encoding of the "view card" page.

Comment: I don't really understand ... I have some Chinese text, I copy this into the form and send it, in the email the Chinese text is being displayed correctly, when I click the url which was generated and open the page, the Chinese text is all messed up, but at the same time I print the same Chinese text and it shows up fine. (I just hard coded the printed text, but it's exactly the same)

Comment: Oh, and the form and the page where the card is being displayed are the same page, if there is some input from $_GET the card is displayed, otherwise it's the form.

Comment: @woutr_be: Nevertheless there is something going on that you have to debug. The base64 function themselves [work fine](http://ideone.com/w0IC2).

Comment: I'm not sure what, when I copy the base64 encoded string directly it seems to work just fine.

So now it seems that when I send the link in the email and people click on it something goes wrong ...

Comment: So here's a little test I did: http://pastebin.com/2Kj4haq9
Apparently the string in the url is not the same from the original...

Comment: I managed to solve it by using urlencode() on the encoded string, it seems some characters were being removed.